# Linq-to-Sql, Use of entity classes and parent/child objects

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, entity

For my project I use SqlCE 3.5, Linq2Sql and generate entity classes (dbml file) with SqlMetal.

If I use extensions of the entity classes as my business object classes, how shall I deal with child objects?

Can I use the existing EntitySet(Of ChildClass) that is already in the dbml file? Or should I create a new collection property in my partial class extension, like:

```
public partial class ParentClass
{
 public List<ChildClass> children { get; set; }
}
```

I got this vague assumption that EntitySet(Of ChildClass) has some type of direct connection to the complete database table. And that I perhaps should use this as purely a data access object, and for business logic, I should keep this other collection object that can hold a subset of the table only.

But I'm not sure if I have totally misunderstood the concept? I really like to know how this should be used properly..?

---

**EDIT1:**

One thing that possibly is a performance issue for me is when binding my object collections to a datagridview. A few properties are updated quite frequently from a stock-exchange data feed, and I wonder if using the EntitySets as the business layer collection makes this slow. Though I **do not call submitchanges on those updates**. Still I'm not able to scroll the datagridview, due to all the updates. May this be due to using the EntitySets, or just the datagridview itself updating so frequently that scrolling will seem impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the entities generated by the Designer, which are Proxy and not real POCO objects you can also use their ObjectSet to get the child colletions. They are of type IQueryable so until you touch one of the item or you use a ToList() or .Where() LinQ extension, EF won't call the database.
Anyway, the BEST PRACTICE is to expose them using an IList and use a Repository to fill the List. The ObjectSet is not only a List, it is also a sort of repository for the entity.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I understood exactly your meaning; With "expose them using an IList and use a Repository to fill the List", do you mean something like first code part of this example (http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html), but returning IList instead of in that example IQueryable ?

Comment: If you return IQueryable every time you apply a Linq filter to the list, like Where, Distinct and so on ... it will call back EF and the database

Comment: I see. Been reading up on POCO, DTOs, Repository etc now.. So starting to see the picture better. Will have to find out if I should decouple this completely, or if instead just be careful how to call the EntitySets.

Comment: I would say that it depends on the number of entities you have, and if it's the first project you do. If you are a newbee on this topic, go slowly, don't try to do everything the first time or it will be too much!
PS: If you believe the answer is right you have to tick it.

Comment: Yes, good point. It's my first work with database, 10-15 tables. 1-tier, single user. But multiple threads due to socket data feed. So far it feels maybe appropriate to have Repositories that use Linq2Sql for data access, with a mapping to return domain object types. Not sure if I like the idea to drag the EntitySets around everywhere, so this would avoid that.